# Question about nextblockhash in bitcoin block struct

Tags: blockchain, json-rpc, mastering-bitcoin, getblock

In the book "Mastering Bitcoin" (3rd edition), on page 46, there is an element `nextblockhash` in the block struct after issuing a `getblock` command, anyone can explain it and how to use it. You know this element will not be known in advance when constructing a block.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `getblock` command is used for retrieving historical blocks, not for constructing a new block. For every block in the currently active chain except for the latest block the next block hash is known.